# How to test self. angularjs controller functions in jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-scope, jasmine, angular-controller

I have the below code inside my controller

Controller:

```
self.DoSomething = function () {
    self.x="hai";
    self.y = function (id, data) {
        self.x="hello";
    }
}

$scope.Call=function(){
    self.DoSomething();
}
```

There is no other self.y function defined other than the given code.

Whenever I test the Call function through jasmine by calling it. My code coverage is not showing inside self.y function. i.e., self.x="hello" is not being called. Please suggest me a way how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`self.y` is not being executed when you call `$scope.Call`. It is only being defined. You do not get coverage for a function unless that function is executed **by your test**. You're going to need to execute `$scope.Call` and then execute `self.y`

## Edit: Example

Somewhere in your Jasmine tests you need to have:

```
describe('y function', function () {
   it('should set self.x to "hello"', function () {
       $scope.Call()
       controllerName.y()
       expect(controllerName.x).toEqual("hello")
   })   
})
```

Comment: Do you mean we can't call it any way? Can you elaborate your answer with some code how to call $scope.y?

Comment: Sorry, meant self.y. And what I mean is that your `self.Call` function does not call `self.y`. You need to call `self.y` to get coverage for it in your tests. Added an example above.

Comment: If this is still confusing then post your test file.

Answer (score 0):

`self.y` is only a property of `self`. The only way to call is is by first define it by calling `$scope.call()` then call `self.y`

```
$scope.call();
self.y();
```

Unless you are exposing `self` from the controller. The code in `self.y` is not testable. If you want it to execute when you call doSomething you must do so explicitly.

```
self.DoSomething = function () {
    self.x="hai";
    self.y = function (id, data) {
        self.x="hello";
    }
    self.y();
}
```

But why are you writing your code like this?

Comment: The code was already written by other team and I do not know exact usage and there is no such call like self.y(); inside the code. I doubt if they are calling it from some directive!. Is it possible to call it explicitly somewhere else? In some places they just wrote var y= function (id, data) {...}. I am not able to test them also.

Comment: Unless `self.y()` is called somewhere in that controller (or possibly from somewhere else, but thats bad design), then that code is never executed in the app and does not need to be tested!